# Cannot import seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, seaborn

I have a problem with importing seaborn. I recently installed "anaconda" on my PC and tried to use seaborn pacjesge. I updated `scipy` and `numpy`. Actually before updating `scipy` python couldn't see `seaborn`. What is problem? Please help me

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:03) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import seaborn as sns
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ed9806ce3570> in <module>()
----> 1 import seaborn as sns

~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .rcmod import *
      2 from .utils import *
      3 from .palettes import *
      4 from .linearmodels import *
      5 from .categorical import *
~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py in <module>()
      1 """Functions that alter the matplotlib rc dictionary on the fly."""
----> 2 import numpy as np
      3 import matplotlib as mpl
      4 
      5 from . import palettes

~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    178         return loader(*packages, **options)
    179 
--> 180     from . import add_newdocs
    181     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    182                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      7 
----> 8 from .type_check import *
      9 from .index_tricks import *
     10 from .function_base import *
~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, \
     13                 obj2sctype, zeros
~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>()
     12 if 'GOTOBLAS_MAIN_FREE' not in os.environ:
     13     os.environ['GOTOBLAS_MAIN_FREE'] = '1'
---> 14 from . import multiarray
     15 os.environ.clear()
     16 os.environ.update(envbak)

ImportError: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

In [2]:
```

Comment: Actually the problem is solved now. Before I tried to update `numpy` using the command `conda install -f numpy`. Now I uninstall `numpy` using `conda uninstall numpy` then reinstall normally `conda install numpy`. This time it said that wants update other related packages.  After that it works fine.

Comment: So I think, if one cannot `import seaborn` after installing `anaconda`, re-installing `scipy` and `numpy` could help. Also rebooting the machine, maybe...

Comment: I had the same problem. You need to install the package directly into iPython, while you're running a notebook.

Answer (score 2):

This finally worked for me on mac.

1. in terminal type: iPython and hit return
2. the interactive python terminal should appear

   IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
    ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
    %quickref -> Quick reference.
    help      -> Python's own help system.
    object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

   In [1]:
3. type: !pip install Seaborn
4. You should see:
    Successfully built Seaborn
    Installing collected packages: Seaborn
    Successfully installed Seaborn-0.7.1
5. Can also try (!conda instead of !pip) but !pip worked for me. Then I tried running the cell in iPython notebook that had "import Seaborn" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just installed the jupyter again, and it works